# Reducing merge commit message in a super simple git workflow — why not rebase?

Tags: git, deployment, merge, devops, rebase

We only have 2-3 developers working on WordPress projects. Our git flow is very simplified with three key branches, `development`, `staging`, and `production`. Pushing to a key branch triggers an automatic build and deploy to the relevant remote server. Pushing to `development` branch builds and deploys to the `development.mysite.org` remote, etc.

We all work on `development` branch for simple stuff and bug fixes. For complex or experimental feature development we spin off `feature` branches from `development`, and merge them back into `development` when complete.

Dev teams tests internally on local and the dev remote. When it passes QA we move the release candidate to staging using `git checkout staging; git pull; git merge development; git push`. `staging` never gets any code that didn't first pass through `development`.

On the staging remote the client reviews the release candidate and denies or approves. If it's denied it goes back to development. If approved, we run release checklists and push code to production via `git checkout production; git pull; git merge staging; git push`. `production` should never receive any code that didn't first pass through `staging`. We push production releases about once per month per client.

The problem is that the above workflow has two irritating flaws — first, it generates a ton of local and remote merge commit messages that clutter the history making it hard to read. Second, it's possible to accidentally commit to the wrong branch which can cause all sorts of workflow problems.

**Question 1:** I want to switch from merging downstream branches to rebasing, but when I `git checkout staging; git rebase development` I get all sorts of merge errors from commits that happened months or years ago. Is this due to switching from merges to rebase? Would this be avoided if we merged every time?

I have no concerns about rewriting history on staging and production because we should never be pushing anything to those branches that did not go through the upstream branches.

**Question 2:** Can branches be set to never accept a push except that it's a merge or rebase from an upstream branch?

**Question 3:** AM I DOING IT ALL WRONG. I feel like I just don't grok the power of rebase. Our system works ok, but sometimes we're hit with hellish git issues and don't really understand why.

Comment: 1/ branches per environment is very often a anti-pattern (I'll let you read about why in many articles online). 2/ Sounds strange that you get conflicts when rebasing staging over Dev if there's no commit on staging directly. 3/ You can merge without a merge commit. 4/ You could also use tags rather than branches. 5/ You can have branch protection if using Gitlab or GitHub. 6/ Without a concrete example of conflict you have, hard to explain why it happens.

Comment: Yes. You can have all of these workflow branches without using true merges. With some care you can use fast-forward merges. Especially if you are willing to reset (rewrite history) those later branches (staging) when something is denied (pushed back to development).

Comment: @GaëlJ do you recommend an articles on using tags per environment rather than branches per environment? Our deploy scripts could be adapted to this.

Comment: @Guildenstern would this be done using ff-only merges? What should I search for to find this pattern?

Comment: @Slam `man gitworkflows`